# How to get array from formCollection

Tags: c#, api

Hi I am using formCollection in my project, I want to get the values as in array that I am sending from javascript. is there a way to do that.
I can only get a single value like that
 `f.GetValues("layout[ali][0]")` 
but I want some generic way to iterate it by converting it to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use .ToArray() for example:

```
ICollection<string> col = new List<string>() { "a","b"};
string[] colArr = col.ToArray();
```